# Breadcrumb is not visible

Tags: panels

I am a newbi to drupal.I installed breadcrumb in my website.It is showing in all pages but one page it is not showing the breadcrumb.I created the page using panels module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module.

> Many new features have been added including support for Views, Panels,
>   Taxonomy vocabularies and terms, paths, and a simple API that allows
>   contributed modules to enable custom breadcrumbs for module pages and
>   theme templates. These are implemented using optional, independent
>   submodules that depend on the main Custom Breadcrumbs module.
>
> In addition to breadcrumb visibility, this version provides an option
>   permitting PHP code snippets to be used in forming the breadcrumb
>   titles and paths. Multiple languages are also supported.

Another option is [Panels Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_breadcrumbs) module.

> Panels Breadcrumbs allows you to set your breadcrumbs directly from
>   Panels configuration, and also allows you to take advantage from
>   Panels arguments and contexts as placeholder tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used path breadcrumb to generate the links to the menu items.Breadcrumb is generating, but links are not enabled.For example i have Articles> content type>>title. If I click on the content type it is not navigating back to the content type.